# File input triggers change event twice (or more)

Tags: javascript

I have a basic `input[file]` element which I hide. When you click on the `#holder` a file explorer pops up. But selecting a file triggers the `console.log()` line to be executed twice (on my computer).

## Beware: the following code below crashes my Chrome tab.

You should better run it as a separate file. Cannot provide a "working" demo, but this is the closest I can get to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```js
var element = document.getElementById('holder');

element.onclick = function(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('file-input');
  input.click();
  input.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    Phimij.addFiles(input.files);
  }, false);
};
```

```css
#holder {
  border: 10px dashed #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#holder.hover {
  border: 10px dashed #333;
}
#file-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
</div>
```

Comment: you are adding the event listener at each click event on the parent. Also, if you do click the input, it will also fire the input's click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`click` events *bubble* up the ancestry tree. That means a click on your `input` will bubble up to your `#holder` element and fire your `click` handler on it. In your `click` handler on `#holder`, you fire the `click` event on the `input`. That's why your browser crashes: You've triggered an infinite loop.

The solution is to hook `click` on the `input` and tell it not to bubble (propagate); see flagged lines (but keep reading, further notes below):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('holder');
// **** Added vvvv
document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
}, false);
// *** Added ^^^^
element.onclick = function(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('file-input');
  input.click();
  input.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    // Phimij.addFiles(input.files);
  }, false);
};
```

```css
#holder {
  border: 10px dashed #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#holder.hover {
  border: 10px dashed #333;
}
#file-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
</div>
```

---

There are a few other things I'd change. You're **adding** a `change` handler to the input **every time** there's a `click` on `#holder`; you really only want to do that once. I'd also add that handler before triggering the click.

So for what it's worth, some changes I'd make:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('holder');
var input = document.getElementById('file-input');

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  input.click();
}, false);

input.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
}, false);
input.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  // Phimij.addFiles(input.files);
}, false);
```

```css
#holder {
  border: 10px dashed #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#holder.hover {
  border: 10px dashed #333;
}
#file-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Kaiido: LOL, I was doing that, too. I really should have up-front.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. Your first two sentences mean that every child element triggers a click event for all parents? Also, thank you for your detailed answer and example!

Comment: @IvankaTodorova: Yes, exactly. A click on an element runs any click handlers on that element, then bubbles ("propagates") to its parent and runs any click handlers on that element, then bubbles to *its* parent and runs any click handlers on it, and so on, until it reaches the root of the document. See [this diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) in the DOM UI Events specification. (You can ignore the "capture" part, it's basically not used in web development, because IE didn't support it until IE9.) Most, but not all, DOM events bubble.

Comment: Thank you very much for all those details. You got it running and I expanded my js knowledge ^^.